# send clientid of another control to javascript via anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have gridview in asp.net as:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipment Received" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="top" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="top">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="#"  id="aShipment"  onclick="javascript:setIdRMA('<%# Eval("idRMA") %>','<%# Eval("idreturn")%>','<%# Eval("idorder")%>','<%# Eval("returnReason")%>','<%# Eval("returnFor")%>','<%# Eval("returnStatus")%>','<%# Eval("dateClosed")%>','<%# Eval("shipmentReceiveDate")%>','<%# Eval("resolution")%>','<%# Eval("sku") %>',lblShipmentReceived.ClientID);">
      <asp:Label ID="lblShipmentReceived" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shipmentReceived")%>'></asp:Label>
    </a>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

on click of anchor tag i am calling setIdRMA method of javascript

I want to send client id of label inside anchor tag to that function.

For that i written as shown in above:

```
lblShipmentReceived.ClientID
```

But this does not get passed.

Please help me.

Comment: lblShipmentReceived does not exists in current context

Comment: What does the rendered (ie. on client) code look like: have the expected values been inserted? What does debugging on the client (use your browser's developer tools) show?

Comment: have you tried:<script>
var cntId = '<%= lblShipmentReceived.ClientID %>';
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `GridView` you may not get `ClientID` directly, you can find `label` which is inside anchor tag by its relative referrance. First pass achor tag element by `this` keyword and access it in the function to find `label`.

`onclick="setIdRMA(..,..,..,this);"`

and in the function

```
function setIdRMA(..,..,..,obj)
{
    var label = $(obj).find('span'); //asp.net label is rendered as span and there is only 1 label so you can use .find()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.children selector](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for this

And `asp:Lable` rendered as `span` on HTML page so you can find it by using `span`

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipment Received" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="top" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="top">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="#"  id="aShipment"  onclick="javascript:setIdRMA(this,'<%# Eval("idRMA") %>','<%# Eval("idreturn")%>','<%# Eval("idorder")%>','<%# Eval("returnReason")%>','<%# Eval("returnFor")%>','<%# Eval("returnStatus")%>','<%# Eval("dateClosed")%>','<%# Eval("shipmentReceiveDate")%>','<%# Eval("resolution")%>','<%# Eval("sku") %>',lblShipmentReceived.ClientID);">
      <asp:Label ID="lblShipmentReceived" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shipmentReceived")%>'></asp:Label>
    </a>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Change your `onclick` function argument and add `this` as first argument in your JavaScript function and then change your javaScript function as below .

```
function setIdRMA(,,,){
   alert($(this).children('span').attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: `jQuery` selectors will always retun all matching elements, since questioner using `GridView`, `$("#idAnchore")` will return as many elements as the rows are. Using this solution it may always return `span` in first anchor tag only.